# Jquery Ajax Call - Read Data

Tags: jquery, ajax

Im trying to read\map my object but cant see how im going wrong?

```
var model = { LastName: templastname, FirstName: tempfirstname, Mobile: tempmobile, AccountId: tempaccountId, Pin: tempPin }
$.ajax({
            url: "/Client/Get/",
            type: 'GET',
            data: $.param(model, true),
            cache: false,
            crossDomain: true,
            async: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {

            },
            error: function (event) {

            },
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            },
        });
```

Controller

```
 public JsonResult GetClient(string model)
        {
            var e = new ClientMapper();
            var objJavascript = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            e = objJavascript.Deserialize<ClientMapper>(model); <--Blows up
}

 private class ClientMapper
        {
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string AccountId { get; set; }
            public string Mobile { get; set; }
            public string Pin { get; set; }
        }
```

Model value:

```
LastName=dfdfdf&FirstName=dfdfdfdf&Mobile=dfdfdf&AccountId=4e82dbfe-2b7f-472c-b66c-0707b1d66ba2&Pin=1234&_=1469644529256
```

Any ideas how I format this correctly?

Comment: which lang is ur controller? Could you paste a copy of the output of ur server code instead.

Comment: @SeeTheC thought so.. If OP is not sure about the C# code, shud add C# and ASP.net tag, else just paste output of the same, required to solve in a client-side perspective

Comment: It looks like on the server, you're expecting JSON, so try sending that: `data: JSON.stringify(model)`. Oh, scratch that, just realized you're making a GET request... now I'm not really sure what you want to do. (Maybe you *should* be sending query parameters but need to handle that properly on the server.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing `string model` in function param write "**ClientMappe**r" make that class public. C# Mvc will aumatically map the json to object

```
public class ClientMapper {....}
public JsonResult GetClient(ClentMapper model)
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's no JSON involved in the current code.

Comment: That said, this code might work anyway if ASP.NET MVC will similarly translate query parameters.